# choosing outbound IP (eth0 or eth1) in FFMPEG

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, centos, ip-address

I have 2 IP addresses on my server.

```
$curl --interface eth0 ifconfig.co      
111.111.111.111

 $curl --interface eth0:0 ifconfig.co      
222.222.222.222
```

So via curl I can switch via interfaces so my IP address changes when I visit any url based on eth IP

How can I use same thing via ffmpeg?

For example, if want to access this video via ffmpeg (it uses 111.111.111.111 to access it)

```
 ffmpeg -i 123.com/video.mp4
```

how can I access same video from my second IP 222.222.222.222 ?

Is there any command like this, perhaps?

```
ffmpeg --interface eth0:0  -i 123.com/video.mp4
```

Comment: Not implemented.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

`ffmpeg` has no such feature. One approach would be to set up a second entry in your `/etc/hosts` file and access it:

```
$ cat /etc/hosts
111.111.111.111  123.com
222.222.222.222  456.com
```

Then access which ever interface you want, using the appropriate DNS entry.

```
$ ffmpeg -i 123.com/...
$ ffmpeg -i 456.com/...
```

Comment: i want to access  123.com which blocked my ip 111.111.111.111
but it doesnt blocked my ip 222.222.222.222
 i can run via curl: $curl --interface eth0:0 123.com   ,and i can access it 
 ,so how can i do same thing with ffmpeg,